# How do you know the location in pix

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

I'm going to try and ask this the best way I can so sorry if I am not clear.

I am trying to learn css and html.

When it comes to positioning a image, for example `top: # px;`, how do I know what the pixel location is? Is there a program for that or is it a guessing game?

I hope you can understand my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the position of a element just by using CSS is not possible. This can be done using javascript. Check this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1409355/1577396) and [link2](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html).

If you know jQuery, it would have been more simpler.
Just use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

> is there a program for that or is it a guessing game?

You can also guess the position of an element when you assigned fixed dimensions to all the elements in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the CSS `top` property in conjunction with `display:absolute` or `fixed`, then yes, it's mostly a guessing game. You can use browser addons to adjust your CSS so that you can see your element being positioned as you change it, get an IDE that supports live updating or previewing, or take a screenshot and measure the pixels yourself.

Normally, however, you shouldn't be placing elements this way. Just let the DOM do it's thing, and use padding and margins to put things into the right place. It takes a bit of trial and error to get things visually appealing, but it really isn't so bad.